# Open Chrome bookmark app in new window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks, google-chrome-app

I am trying to build a bookmark app for Chrome by following the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2714278?hl=en). This is the sample `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Google Apps Certification app",
  "description": "Link to Google Apps Certification website",
  "version": "1.1",
  "icons": {
    "128": "128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "http://certification.googleapps.com/app-info/"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://certification.googleapps.com/"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "notifications"
  ]
}
```

It works fine for my page, but I like to open it in a separate window (which gives it a standalone impression on the Chromebook). Is this possible by just changing the json? I can't seem to find the relevant documentation on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **[this guide](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide#manifest)** the `container` property (inside `launch`) and set it to `panel`, e.g.:

```
"apps": {
    ...
    "launch" {
        "web_url": "http://certification.googleapps.com/",
        "container": "panel",
        /*optional*/ "height": xxx,
        /*optional*/ "width": yyy
    }
}
```

---

BTW, are you sure you are after a hosted app (i.e. points to an already deployed and externally hosted web-app) and not a packaged app (i.e. includes all necessary code in a .crx package and is locally installed and deployed) ?

A packaged app can declare a background script, which can handle the **[`chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_runtime.html#event-onLaunched)** event, which grants more freedom on how you launch your app, e.g.:

```
/* `In manifest.json`: */
"app": {
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}

/* In `background.js`: */
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('main.html', {
        bounds: {
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            left: 100,
            top: 100
        },
        minWidth: 800,
        minHeight: 600,
        ...
    });
});
```

For the full list of available options, take a look **[here](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#method-create)**.

For an overview of packaged apps, you can start **[here](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle.html)**.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I indeed want to move to a packaged app in the future, for now I was just curious how native you could make a simple bookmark look ;) 
PS I can't believe how I read over the container option :O I guess I was too focused on the 'window' keyword...

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
{
    ...
    "display": "fullscreen",
    ...
}
```

Check the link for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Manifest#display